# How do i retrieve a unit of a qualifier in a statement group in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to get all IBA cocktail entities, including their recipe, from Wikidata.
All terms i use are taken the [wikidata documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary/en-gb).

The query should return the name of the cocktail, all ingredients and their quantity (amount and unit).
[My query](https://w.wiki/a$u) returns everything i listed except the unit of the ingredient:

```
SELECT ?cocktail ?cocktailLabel ?cocktailDescription ?material ?quantity ?unit ?ingredient ?ingredientLabel WHERE {
  ?cocktail wdt:P31 wd:Q2536409; # cocktails from the IBA official cocktail list
            p:P186 ?material.    # get statement of materials used
  ?material ps:P186 ?ingredient; # get ingredient entity from materials used
            pq:P1114 ?quantity.  # get quantity of the relation
  OPTIONAL {
    ?cocktail p:P186/psn:P186 [wikibase:quantityUnit ?unit ].
  }
  MINUS { ?material wdt:P31 wd:Q81727. } #remove cups from materials
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

This [statement node](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/statement/Q1816386-70a0530a-4b4d-3feb-abbb-d88c93fbaebe) should yield the identifier of cognac, the label of cognac, the amount (in this case 3) and the unit of 3 cognac (in this case **centilitres**).

What do I have to add to query?

Comment: `SELECT ?cocktail ?cocktailLabel ?cocktailDescription ?materialStmt ?quantity ?unitLabel ?ingredient ?ingredientLabel WHERE {
  ?cocktail wdt:P31 wd:Q2536409; 
            p:P186 ?materialStmt.    
  ?materialStmt ps:P186 ?ingredient; 
           pqv:P1114 [ wikibase:quantityAmount     ?quantity ;
  wikibase:quantityUnit       ?unit ].
  MINUS { ?material wdt:P31 wd:Q81727. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?cocktail)`

Comment: hey, thanks for your input. this helped me very much and solved my problem! do you want to post your comment into the answer section? then i can mark the issue as solved and you will be marked as the contributor who solved it :)